# highlighting/bold text in sqlite full text search

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, fts3, fts4

I want to know whether SQLite FTS3 and FTS4 support hit highlighting? Documentation says **snippet function can be used for text formatting**. I implemented the same but it does not return formatted text. My detailed code in an unanswered questions is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565218/sqlite-snippet-function-implementation-does-not-format-text-as-html-in-textview)

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `snippet()` definitely works, as I use FTS3 indexing in the APK edition of my book, and I am able to highlight the matches in bold.

Comment: @MikeofSST It is! but it does not have any answer for the mentioned question.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your response! Can you please check my code in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565218/sqlite-snippet-function-implementation-does-not-format-text-as-html-in-textview)